# How can I manually create my own object during deserialization?

Tags: java, deserialization

The default behavior of Serializable creates the object in a special way independent of constructors. Serializable will by default use reflection to read and write all non-transient non-static fields.

Externalizable on the other hand doesn't use reflection and is therefore faster but requires you to do things yourself: this is what I want.

> During deserialization Class.newInstance() will be used. This means that the Externalizable class must have a public no-arg constructor.

A public no-arg constructor is unacceptable and sometimes even impossible in the case of a non-static final field.

With a bit of digging I found android.os.Parcelable which allows me to create the object myself. There's also com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.IdentifiedDataSerializable but I'd have to create a factory class and register it and it just looks like a lot of unnecessary work compared to Parcelable.

My code is not android and currently uses no libraries. So I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to use Parcelable in non-android Java code?
2. What's the easiest way/lowest impact library that will allow me to create and return my own objects during deserialization? Also the library can't cost money.

And yes I am aware of serialization proxies but that isn't the point of the question.

Comment: [kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) maybe? I would still like to know my options.

Comment: So what exactly *is* the point of the question? Serialization appears to fit the bill perfectly. Obviously the answer to (1) is no, as Parcelable isn't part of Java.

Comment: I want more control than Externalizable gives me. I want to be able to read the data from the stream and decide to call a constructor or factory or reuse an already existing object etc. I know there's readResolve but I'm trying to avoid using that for a different reason.

Comment: What about using `readObject` and `writeObject` on your class that implements `Serializable`? In that way you control how to serialize/deserialize the object.

Comment: Parcelable on deserialization calls the custom static method passing in the stream. The method then decides how and if to create an object. Serializable/Externalizable on the other hand creates the object then passes in the stream to a non-static method then uses readResolve which might throw away the created object. I was hoping for an equivalent to Parcelable. If it isn't reasonably possible to do then I'll just stick with Serializable with read/write Object. It's mostly preference (one less object being created doesn't really matter).

Answer (score 0):

One (admittedly partial) solution is to have Externalizable only on the "root" class of any object tree that you are trying to serialize. Any fields it contains including deep copies of object references can be serialized by passing the ObjectInput to your factory methods (or to a constructor that takes ObjectInput). This allows all except the root object to be immutable etc.

Of course this won't help if the root object of your object tree is the one that cannot have a no-arg constructor.